# Saving individual information from leaflet csv

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, coordinates, mapbox

So my code currently displays markers that are read from a csv file, draw a path between them in order of appearance and animate another marker along the path.
What I would like to know how to do, is retrieve an individual marker's csv information (what I do in the eachLayer function is use layer.feature."nameofcolumn" to retrieve that info for EACH marker) so that I can save that as a variable and then be able to play around with it.
The idea is that I can open a second web-page and transfer that variable over to it, but that's another issue.
Here's my code so far:

```
    <?php
$currentPage = 'map';?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Leaflet Everything!</title>

    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>

    <script src='//api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.1/mapbox.js'></script>

    <link href='//api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet'>

    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-omnivore/v0.2.0/leaflet-omnivore.min.js'></script>

    <script src='//api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v0.4.0/leaflet.markercluster.js'></script>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

    <script src="./js/leaflet-measure-path.js"></script>

    <link href='//api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v0.4.0/MarkerCluster.css' rel='stylesheet'>

    <link href='//api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v0.4.0/MarkerCluster.Default.css' rel='stylesheet'>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="MovingMarker.js"></script>

    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:static; width:80%; height:80%;}
        table {
            border-collapse : collapse;
            border : 2px black solid;
            font : 12px sans-serif;
        }
        td {
            border : 1px black solid;
            padding : 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Interactive Map </h1>
    <a href = index.php>Home</a>
    <br>
    <a href = map2.php>map2</a>
    <br>
    <a href = leaflet.html>clicky map</a>
    <div id='map'></div>
    <script>
        var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'faraday2.hb90naie', {
        detectRetina: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        //take away the zoom controls on the top left
        infoControl: false,
        maxZoom: 15
        });
        map.setView([-34.0153, 93.1673], 4);

        function displayCSV(){
            d3.text("./data/data2.csv", function(data){
                var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

                var container = d3.select("body")
                .append("table")

                .selectAll("tr")
                    .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                    .append("tr")
                .selectAll("td")
                    .data(function(d) {return d;}).enter()
                    .append("td")
                    .text(function(d) {return d;});
            });
        }

        function eachLayer(layer) {
            var feature = layer.toGeoJSON();
            //if (feature.properties && feature.properties.data.title) {
                //layer.bindPopup("Name - " + feature.properties.title);
            //}
        }

        var moderateIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl : './img/moderate.png',
            iconSize : [25, 25]
        })

        var highIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl : './img/high.png',
            iconSize : [25, 25],

        })

        var extremeIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl : './img/extreme.png',
            iconSize : [25, 25]
        })

        var trainIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl : './img/train.png',
            iconSize : [25, 25]
        })

        var latlngs = [];
        var points = omnivore.csv('./data/data2.csv')
        .on('ready', function() {
            map.fitBounds(points.getBounds());

            points.eachLayer(function(layer){
                if(layer.feature.properties.priority == 'high'){
                    layer.setIcon(highIcon);
                }
                else if(layer.feature.properties.priority == 'extreme'){
                    layer.setIcon(extremeIcon);
                }
                else if(layer.feature.properties.priority == 'moderate'){
                    layer.setIcon(moderateIcon);
                }

                layer.bindPopup("Type of fault: " +
                 layer.feature.properties.type + 
                 "<br> Priority :" + 
                 layer.feature.properties.priority + 
                 "<br>" + 
                 layer.feature.geometry.coordinates + 
                 "<br>" + 
                 layer.feature.properties.meme + 
                 "-" + 
                 layer.feature.properties.time + 
                 "<br>Time from previous marker:" + 
                 layer.feature.properties.timeDif + 
                 "<br>Total time(end marker): " + 
                 layer.feature.properties.totalTime +
                 "<br>" +
                 "<a href=" + 
                 layer.feature.properties.link +
                 ">Click here for more information</a>" );

                latlngs.push(layer.getLatLng());
            });
            L.polyline(latlngs, {color: "blue", 
                showMeasurements : true, 
                measurementOptions :{minDistance : 0}
            }).addTo(map);

            var myMovingMarker = L.Marker.movingMarker(latlngs, 20000, {autostart : true, loop : true, icon : trainIcon}).addTo(map);

            var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
                showCoverageOnHover: false,
                maxClusterRadius: 25
            });
            markers.addLayer(points);
            //window.alert(markers.length);
            map.addLayer(markers);
            points.eachLayer(eachLayer);

        }).addTo(map);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my issue by creating a javascript class that creates an array of points.
for anyone curious, I've included a sample of the class.

```
//Function for managing points in a list/array
PointManager = function(){
    //array of points
    var points = [];
    //function that adds points into the array
    this.addPoint = function(point){
        if (!typeof(point) == Point)
            throw 'Invalid Object';

        var keyArray = [point.getLat(), point.getLong()];
        points[keyArray] = point;
    }
    //function that returns point information
    this.getPoint = function(lat, long){
        var keyArray = [lat, long];
        return (points[keyArray] == undefined) ? null : points[keyArray];
    }
    //function that returns all point information
    this.getAllPoints = function(){
        return points;
    }

    this.deletePoints = function(point){
        points = [];
        // console.log(points);
    }

}
```